# How to make a TextBox update its source ListBox's SelectedValue (without code-behind?)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF and am really trying to drill down on binding until I can do it like a boss.  But I'm having a bit of an issue.

In xaml, I have a ListBox like so:

```
<ListBox Name="AccountsDisplay"
    SelectedValuePath="Username"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}"
    />
```

And I have a TextBox that's pulling "Username" from said ListBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=AccountsDisplay, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

**Note:**  Accounts is both an ObservableCollection and all objects added to it are of type Account, which is purely a data class that extends INotifyPropertyChanged, and has properties such as Username, Password, etc.

The TextBox is pulling the Username property properly, and updates any time I change selection in the ListBox (which is populated with pretty lil' Account info entries, as intended), but I cannot then click on the TextBox and attempt to update the Username portion of entries in the ListBox.

My gut tells me I'm going about this TextBox the wrong way, since I won't be able to make other TextBoxes and pull any additional Account properties (thanks to SelectedValuePath already having a value), but I'm too new to WPF & XAML to see where the error is in my ways!

Am I barking up the right tree, or is there a more appropriate way to get a TextBox to synchronize with (and edit) the data in another UI Element?

Comment: have you tried adding `Mode=TwoWay` to the TextBox binding?

Comment: as far as I know `Mode=TwoWay` by default (for a TextBox), but in fact sometimes we have to set it explicitly (no clue on why, although I tried checking the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` of the FrameworkPropertyMetadata of the `TextProperty` and it reported true). Also note that to see the changes, you have to switch focus to another control from the TextBox or set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for the Binding.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `SelectedValue` at all, given that you synchronize the current item you could probably use `{Binding Accounts/Username}`. Edit: As King mentioned the binding may already work, so try changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` as suggested.

Comment: Ahah!  Switching to `{Binding Accounts/Username}` along with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` makes it work beautifully!  The `Mode=TwoWay` snippet is interesting to know, but seems to have been working 'by default' once I was binding directly instead of through `SelectedValue`.  **Edit:** I'm new to posting on StackOverflow too (instead of just lurking)... can/should I mark this closed or give you guys points or something?

Answer (score 0):

Consider binding to the property of the actual DataContext of the list item selected.
I do not use SelectedValue because I am not sure of it's purpose.
Because of my ignorance regarding the use of that particular property, I just rely on SelectedItem.
I can then specify the property name that I want to bind to relative to the DataContext of the selected list item.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=AccountsDisplay, Path=SelectedItem.Username}"/>
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer.*